# Where did Nietzsche say he was not the overman?

Tags: nietzsche, nihilism

Where did Nietzsche say he was not the overman?

I know that Zarathustra does too, but seems to be.

I'm interested because I can't easily conceive of a more thorough nihilist, at least without AI enhancements (and it seems obvious Nietzsche wasn't talking or preparing us for computers).

Comment: [Domino, Nietzsche's Use of Amor Fati in Ecce Homo](https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.5325/jnietstud.43.2.0283): "*At the end of “Why I Am So Clever,” he mentions amor fati. By the time his readers reach this section, Nietzsche has made it clear that he has failed to live up to the ideal of amor fati... Nietzsche succeeds in getting his readers to focus on the teaching, not the teacher.*"  Maybe not.

Comment: i can't read that, but thanks @Conifold